sample example of java upgrade from 8 to 21 using open rewrite
I have a springboot application with version 2.x and using java 8, I would like to upgrade the java VERSION TO 21 and spring boot version to 3.x,
My question is which is the easiest way to upgrade these frameworks. and how to upgrade using open rewrite using maven

In the future it might help to include what you have already read and tried in your answer, such that you get better answers. It also helps show that you've put in effort before asking a question, or where any confusion might have been.

This page shows you how to upgrade to spring boot 3.3 and Java 21:
https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/springboot3bestpractices
Under usage there is a command you can copy for Maven that should run as is:
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:run -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-spring:RELEASE -Drewrite.activeRecipes=org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.SpringBoot3BestPractices -Drewrite.exportDatatables=true

Hope that helps!
